# Double backslashes disappear from code

Tags: bug, markdown

Not the first time it happens on the site, so it's time to raise the problem in Meta.

It is similar, but distinct from [‘double backslash + newline’ collapses to ‘single backslash’ when I hit ‘edit’](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/double-backslash-newline-collapses-to-single-backslash-when-i-hit-edit) (Nov 26 '10); what happens is that code with lines ending with `\\` gets randomly transformed, without *any* intervention, into a single backslash and the following line becomes a continuation of the line previously ending with `\\`.

The code for sure ***had*** double backslashes when it was posted.

See the edit history at https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/146730/revisions (Nov 24 '13) for the last time I was made aware by it in some code of mine, look at the comment [How to typeset row operations on augmented matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/how-to-typeset-row-operations-on-augmented-matrix/146730#comment854996_146730)

- Another case I remember is [How to correctly format (and align) a LaTeX proof?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/how-to-correctly-format-and-align-a-latex-proof) (Sep 2 '11) where my answer was fixed by Andrew Swann and, when I went to see what edit had been done, I discovered the same problem in azetina's answer.
- Here is another example: [How to align a set of multiline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations/44451#44451) (Feb 13 '12) (a second degraded answer, by Werner, fixed; Feb 13 '12; except that the intended fix isn't present, but fixed now)

Other examples:

- [Vertically align cell table in figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/85216/2) (Dec 2 '12)
- [Set math fonts to predefined color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/131555/3) (Sep 4 '13)
- [Using \gather and \align together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50483/using-gather-and-align-together) (Apr 3 '12) (all answers, but not the question, are affected)
- [Label rows of a matrix by characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/59732/2) (Jun 13 '12)
- [Hyperref TextFields dont't work when in tabular environment with xetex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135225/hyperref-textfields-dontt-work-when-in-tabular-environment-with-xetex) (Sep 26 '13) (the question)
- [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/47171/revisions) (Mar 7 '12)
- [Commutative Diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/113823) (May 23 '13)
- [How to create alternating rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/5365/revisions) (Nov 14 '10) (an answer)
- [Modify `eqnarray` to match that of `amsmath`'s `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/96210/2) (Jan 31 '13)
- [Table overlay in `beamer` on multiple rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/83734/3) (Nov 21 '12)
- [Rotated column titles in `tabular`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/32687/2) (Oct 25 '11)
- [Diagram of an artificial neural network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/132471/5) (Sep 9 '13)
- [Aligning plain `align` and `cases`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/33380/3) (Nov 1 '11)
- [TikZ matrix as a replacement for tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18521/101651) (May 18 '11) (both question and answer)
- [vertical-lines-in-a-multirow-and-multicolumn-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88972/vertical-lines-in-a-multirow-and-multicolumn-table/88975?noredirect=1#comment871408_88975) (Jan 2 '13)

### Update

In view of the provisional answer given below, please only add examples that appear to be affected ***after February 22, 2015***, below this comment.

Latest date (so far) of corrected example:  December 20, 2013: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150816/579.  (Please update
this date if a later example is found.  The aim is to pinpoint the likely period in which the offending change was applied in order to determine the cause.)

### Examples

(empty, for now, hope it remains so)

### Update: April 27, 2017

Nick Craver seems to have found the origin of the problem. While he blames himself, I think we shouldn't put him at the wall and fire. `;-)`

The proposal he made seems quite appealing, particularly if the items edited while in the specific review queue aren't bumped to the top page. With all candidates collected in a queue, we should be able to get away with the issue soon.

An additional request would be to have two buttons: “Fix” and "Pull off the queue”, the latter for posts that are just false positive.

A good search criterion for a post being included in the list seems to be

> it contains a backslash followed by four spaces or a TAB, and has been posted before 2013-12-31

Comment: the "how to align" example has been corrected, but if someone notices it degrading again, i'd really like to hear about it.

Comment: Please, add examples when you find them

Comment: All answers (but not the question itself) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50483/ seem to have been hit.

Comment: presumably a duplicate of this unanswered bug report from 2015 http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/something-messed-with-my-answers-backslashes-and-newlines?rq=1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but maybe prodding the Powers is better

Comment: @egreg sure, I just thought the powers like to be reminded that it was flagged before....

Comment: I can verify that I have also observed this vanishing of the final backslash and the following newline from answers containing `\\\`.  It is rather frustrating, and needs to be fixed. I have not been keeping track of answers that I have seen affected.

Comment: I don't quite see why this is *distinct*, as it says in the question, as opposed to worth banging a drum about because of the utter lack of response to earlier attempts to raise the issue.

Comment: @cfr -- although the premise of this question is the same as the other, that one doesn't have the list of examples which is a valuable adjunct.  so if any question is to be closed as a duplicate, i'd vote for having the other one closed, pointing to this one.  i'm just bothered (*very* bothered) by the fact that it's gotten no action after so long.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The worst thing is that it is ***not*** distinct. If it was a new problem, you could understand it not having been addressed.

Comment: I'm looking into it this week

Comment: @m0sa: thank you for looking into this bug. That said, the question is more than one month old and it's causing havoc in the site, as it breaks working code. Why did it take so long for the Powers That Be to look at us?

Comment: For those interested in *searching* for mistakes, here's a possible search criteria: [`tabular code:"\ " created:2015-02-22..2017-01-31`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tabular+code%3A%22%5C+%22+created%3A2015-02-22..2017-01-31). This is based on the fact that (1) ``\\`` is typically associated with `tabular`s; (2) the code change will have a "control space"; (2) was created after Feb 22, 2015.

Comment: ...of course, change the query to suit your needs; for example, `align` and `matrix` are other environments that also use ``\\`` (to name a few). Also, if you wish to correct posts that have been affected (limiting such corrections to a few per day and not flood the home page with edit bumps), adjust the `created` search accordingly.

Comment: Just want to say "thanks" to those who are diligently going through old answers and fixing this (specially @barbarabeeton).

Comment: I don't know if this could be useful, but here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/11717/revisions I found \ followed by tab.

Comment: Just want to say "thanks" also to Moriambar who is fixing a lot of old posts at an impressive pace.

Comment: Although fixing these posts is an important job, it's making the front page basically unusable. I'm not sure this is a net win. An option to mark edits as minor and thus not bump the post would be extremely useful here. I'd be in favor of waiting until something like this is implemented before fixing all of these.

Comment: @TH. I agree, that's why i asked for the special queue

Comment: @egreg, right. That would be good too. But lacking that, all of the backslash fixing seems quite disruptive. (Of course, none of these comments should be taken to mean I'm not appreciative of all the work that's going into fixing this!)

Comment: @TH. I fix posts when I happen to find them, not searching for them.

Answer (score 30):

Update: **This was almost certainly my fault.**

On December 20, 2013 I moved the TeX (and meta) databases to new homes. I'm not sure how the original problem occurred, but TeX and its meta had a very odd database collation. Of the hundreds of databases, it was only those. We didn't recognize this for several years until we started aggregating data across databases for several network screens (think: top bar, achievements, rep, etc.).

The only way to fix this *online* and permanently (not ending up with a two-off database with a different structure) was to make a new Tex database and migrate things over. This happened by making TeX/meta read-only, moving the data in the background, and swapping the connection over at the end. But it appears that the strange collation the database was on handled double backslashes particularly in an odd way that did not convert to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` cleanly.

I looked back at our internal chat logs, and a hint that this was an issue didn't reach our ears until July 15th, 2015. Unfortunately, we don't keep data forever and by years later, those database backups were long gone.

We can't just fix this because we don't have the data, but we're looking at options to help scale out fixing this quickly, for example possibly a new review queue we can populate with these posts for quick fixing by many. We don't have the data to do this with 100% accuracy, and we can't trust a query would be 100% accurate either, but populating a queue to very quickly.

Before we go down that road, **is that an appealing option?** There are other uses for such functionality, e.g. when we detect images that are no longer there and posts need some love, etc.

Comment: The option is appealing! Would it be possible that edits to those posts aren't bumped to the top page?

Comment: @egreg That's a perfectly valid requirement - adding that to the discussion list, we should be able to do that.

Comment: to echo @egreg, that would be *very* appealing!  we've found another condition that resulted in corrupted code, and i think it's mentioned in a comment somewhere on this page.  so we can come up with some additional patterns to search, to populate your database.  and not bumping would be really beneficial.  some of us will be at the tex users group meeting next week, and i can probably conscript some (reasonably willing) volunteers.

Comment: thank you for doing the research and 'fessing up.

Comment: Thanks, I appended some details to the question

Comment: The special review list would be helpful but http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/revision/646030/806504/corruption suggests there are still thousands of these so it will take a while in the web interface. In practice the likelihood of a single backslash followed by four spaces is so small for TeX code that I think you do in fact have the data to fix this in the back end. If you changed all single backslash followed by four spaces to double backslash newline four spaces, it is theoretically possible that you corrupt a couple of answers but you will have fixed over 6000, so a net win. ..

Comment: .. Especially if you could put any affected documents in a review queue for quick review by volunteers after an automated fix. (egreg's "fix button" suggestion would also work, either way is quicker than actually making the replacement in the existing browser edit interface, or copying the text to emacs, fixing and copying back.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- although there are probably some places where the code legitimately has a backslash followed by multiple spaces, i think your proposed automatic fix, with "quick review", is feasible and a good idea.  there are also some instances of backslash + tab + lost line ending, though many fewer than the four-space instances.  (tab apparently works nicely as a substitute for four spaces to identify code. sigh.)

Comment: @NickCraver: Please, please, take a look at this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37326048#37326048 Looks like a DB collation error.

Comment: @NickCraver: Just like the ``\\``-gone-missing, this Unicode character shows it's presence from the first post. I doubt I've seen that before, so just wonder whether this is related.

Comment: @NickCraver Can we hope for the queue to be activated?

Comment: @NickCraver BTW, I hope you have noticed that because you refused to fix it automatically, members of the community have been manually going through thousands of post and editing them: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue -- this is thankless work and I've seen such volunteer efforts lead to burnout in other communities.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR We're not refusing to fix anything, we just haven't had the time to get to this. My team is responsible for *many* things and this is one of a sea of them. I also get pinged at a minimum of dozens of times a day across the network and chat...I don't get to every message (there aren't enough hours in the day). I'm really glad the community is stepping up here, but I'd be lying if I said I'll have time to assist in the near future. There's a lot in progress and all of it higher priority - that's the no-BS status of things at the moment.

Comment: @NickCraver Was your profile inspired by this [image](http://www.aertoluna.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/padroiero-site.png)?

Answer (score 15):

Based on [\\ corruption](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/revision/646030/806504/corruption), I've created a new query

[TeX.SX \\ corruption (based on user ID)](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/676480/tex-sx-corruption-based-on-user-id)

which I hope will help anyone to find their own posts affected by this bug!

P.S. The database is updated every sunday, so the query will return also updated Q&A until the database is refreshed...

Answer (score 5):

This and the linked question

[‘double backslash + newline’ collapses to ‘single backslash’ when I hit ‘edit’](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/double-backslash-newline-collapses-to-single-backslash-when-i-hit-edit)

Are two manifestations of the same issue, see

[Community effort in fixing the double backslashes issue](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7317/1090)

For a summary of how this got fixed in the end.

Answer (score 4):

I've looked into it and I couldn't find anything specific. The thing is, we don't ever modify markdown w/o recording history. So when you read about rebakes and other stuff we do, those are affecting the conversion from markdown to html, with markdown always staying the same.

To me, this looks like a one off job that somebody ran on the DB that touched post history (where markdown is stored). This would still leave the HTML of the post the same. The same holds true for markdown updates. Everything happens in the rebake.

Recently, however, we did multiple rebakes. One was adding `rel="noreferrer"` to links in order to mitigate the `window.opener` vulnerability, and another one was for fixing imgur links to https (which again was only a rebake). Those rebakes then surfaced the markdown change, long after it happened.

So the question that still has no answer is, who touched the post history (and when). Unfortunately I couldn't find the answer to that. But it's definitely not caused by anything that's running in production currently.

Comment: at least some of us understand the difficulty of tracking something like this down.  (in my day job, i've been bedeviled by software that *doubles* backslashes instead of turning doubles into singles, and similarly trashing code that's supposed to be cut and pasted by end users.  the folks in charge here can't figure that out either.)  i'll ask on the chat for people finding future instances to check the date of the posting, and report anything later than the *original* report, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5978/, from 22 feb 2015, which was never even acknowledged.

Comment: that would be awesome

Comment: please take a look at this set of revisions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/229149/revisions -- it is dated right around the time of the original report.  the initial input wasn't entered as code, and it was edited to make it so.  the initial input shows *single* backslashes, but the side-by-side markdown shows double backslashes in the alleged original.  something very fishy there!

Comment: i've added the dates on which the corrupted entries were reported as having been posted.  all predate the 22 feb 2015 date of the initial bug report.

Comment: @m0sa: What does "bake" mean here?

Comment: Bake: take the latest markdown, generate html, and store it in the db. The html from the db is what is shown to the users.

Comment: @m0sa The problem is seemingly not happening now, but it happened before and we have no idea how many posts have been affected. It is quite obvious that some version of the SE engine converted `<double backslash><endline>` into something nasty, probably during db UPDATE. I'm quite sure that this wasn't happening on users' PCs --- how would the users do this when they simply fill in a TEXTAREA and send it to the server?

Comment: @barbarabeeton and I have each now fixed several hundred of these posts, but there are hundreds more in the system, it is painful to track them down given the public search tools. Given that this was a system corruption, is there any chance of the stack Exchange team toing a custom search over the back end and producing a list of suspect posts that could be checked manually?

Comment: the corruption turned `\\<newline>` in code sections into `\ ` so the main marker is `\    ` in a code block but searching for `code:"\    "` is same as `code:"\ "` spaces are collapsed, also want to avoid false hits for `\\ ` If a seach could be done over the internal files for a regex `[^\\]\\    ` (not-bs,bs, 4 spaces) and the list of  matching posts made available it would greatly help fixing this issue.

Comment: instead of four spaces after some of the corrupted double backslashes, there is something else -- i think it's a tab.  here's an example of such a case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95694/579 .  it's deleted, but i doubled the backslashes anyway, to get one more item off the search list.  look at the next element following the double backslashes in the code; it spaces over more than one space when advancing with the right-arrow key.

Comment: Please see this query to see an estimate of the size of the problem http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/revision/646030/806504/corruption   The vast majority of the 7322 posts returned by this query will have been corrupted by this change as a single backslash followed by four spaces is _very_ rare. fixing 7000 posts by hand through the web interface using volunteer labour is going to be tricky

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hats off to your incredible effort !

Comment: @percusse -- thanks.  it's rather discouraging that whatever happened was not done under any controls that kept a record.  i think we may never be entirely free of the mess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did several hundred but stopped once I saw there were over 7000 left. the above query suggests that there are still over 6000 left  **It should be _really easy_ for this this to be fixed as a single bulk edit by stackexchange staff** it is nonsense that we are expected to fix these one at a time in the web interface.

Comment: @m0sa still no news?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- when my brain needs a rest from (1) trying to figure out a problem with `tikzpicture` `\draw[transparent]` or writing a talk for bachotug, i do a bunch more of these.  yes, it'll still take about a year to finish at this rate, even flooding the "active" list.  bah, humbug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying to determine when exactly this happened and why. We're worried about doing a mass update when this _may_ happen again. It will be a bit of time though because I'm going to be digging through historical data.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @bluefeet: Thanks for the feedback! Could you please keep us updated on your progress? A lot of good people is devoting part of their time fixing this issue, and it would be horrible if this issue happens again, not to mention the collective feeling.

Comment: @bluefeet -- one more thanks for the update.  would it be possible, given the huge number of postings still to be corrected (which we *will* do, and which will inevitably pollute the active list undesirably), to provide an option, *strictly for this exercise*, to *not* move to the active list?  having users discouraged from looking at the active list because of this pollution is only slightly less discouraging than having them cut and paste from an uncorrected block of code and complain that it doesn't work.

Comment: please see  the question today https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366530/table-with-booktabs-cannot-obtain-desired-result  Yet another visitor to the site completely confused by the fact that the answers have been completely corrupted. **Please** is there any possibility of you ever fixing this?

Comment: @bluefeet BTW, I hope you have noticed that because you refused to fix it automatically, members of the community have been going through thousands of posts and editing them manually: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue -- this is thankless work and I've seen such volunteer efforts lead to burnout in other communities. You may not care but I hope you are aware.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I wouldn't say that we're refusing to fix anything, we've got a huge backlog of projects and items in the queue that also have attention. It's fantastic that the community has been taking time to fix up these issues, and yes, we'd like to get something implemented to make this easier we just haven't gotten around to it yet.