# What happened with `\\` on my answers

Tags: bug

Suddenly, a lot of my old answers are being edited  because instead of `\\`  in table or some other code appear `\`. joined with the next line.

It is impossible that I posted so many answers with this mistake. In a site so active it is also impossible a wrong code undetected for a long time, not to say dozens of answers with positive votes.

Someone has noticed the same problem? What happened?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, I did not realize it was a duplicate question.

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/community-effort-in-fixing-the-double-backslashes-issue please